# Тире в предложении с приложением

Tags: тире, приложение

***Здесь мало жителей, – отсюда, собственно, и походит название поселка – Маложитейский.***

Правильна ли пунктуация в предложении? Понимаю, что возможно обойтись и без знаков препинания в конце предложения, то есть без тире, однако по какому правилу в данном случае тире ставится?

Comment: А зачем запятая при тире?

Comment: Запятая и тире ставится перед присоединительным предложением, содержащим дополнительное замечание